# Angular2 cannot pass in multiple parameters on PUT request. SyntaxError: Unexpected token "at parse....”

Tags: angular, put

I’m new to Angular2, TypeScript, and OOP. I have a service that takes in three parameters: A user, an id, and a description. I have those params contained within a `Notes` class and passed into the `updateDashNotesMethod()` within the service where I’m executing the `PUT` request. The `Notes` class is imported into my component and passed into the method where I’m subscribing to the `updateDashNotesMethod` in my service.

I’m getting a `400 error “SyntaxError: Unexpected token "at parse.......”`. When I log to the console from my service and component I’m only getting the “user”. Nothing else is getting passed in.

I’ve used Postman to test these endpoints and they work like a charm so I know it’s something I’m doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here’s my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Notes } from './notes';

@Injectable()
export class CetoService {

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

updateDashNotesMethod(notes: Notes) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let url = `http://bla:4000/api/path/path/`;
console.log('From Service ' + JSON.stringify(notes));
return this._http
          .put(url, JSON.stringify(notes), {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch(this.handleError);
}

error response code.....
```

Here's my notes class

```
export class Notes{
  user:string;
  query_id:number;
  description:string;
}
```

Here's my Component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, ElementRef, Directive, Input,  Output  } from '@angular/core';
import { CetoService } from '../services/ceto.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DashboardPipe } from '../filters/dashboard.pipe';
import { SharedqueryPipe } from '../filters/sharedquery.pipe';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Notes } from '../services/notes';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-dashboard',
   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
   providers: [CetoService]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private __dashdata: CetoService) {}

ngOnInit() {

}

updateDashNotes(notes: Notes){
  console.log('Passed in Object... ' + notes)
  this.__dashdata.updateDashNotesMethod(notes).subscribe()
}
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="description_form">
    <textarea name="notes" [(ngModel)]="dashboard.txt_Description" class="form-control" type="text" rows="6"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right dash-btn" (click)="updateDashNotes(dashboard.txt_User_Name, dashboard.id_Query_ID, dashboard.txt_Description)">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right dash-btn" (click)="cancelEdit(dashboard)" *ngIf="dashboard.isEditing">Cancel</button>                                             
 </form>
```

Comment: prams? you've only got two hands, how many do you expect to be able push? haha (your title)

Comment: Update: Forgot to put notes in the constructor.

     constructor(public _notes: Notes) {}

I didn't set the parameters to the properties of the Notes
     updateDashNotes(user: string, id: number, description: string){

    this._notes.user = user,
    this._notes.query_id = id,
    this._notes.description = description
    
    console.log('notes output' + JSON.stringify(this._notes))
    this.__dashdata.updateDashNotesMethod(this._notes).subscribe()
  }

It is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Your view does

```
(click)="updateDashNotes(dashboard.txt_User_Name, dashboard.id_Query_ID, dashboard.txt_Description)
```

But the method is declared as

```
updateDashNotes(notes: Notes) {
```

So, instead of passing a Notes instance to your method, you're passing 3 arguments.

I'm surprised you didn't notice that by just looking at the output of your console logs. The network tab of your browser dev tools is also very useful in that kind of situation.

Also, note that setting the Content-Type header and stringifying the argument is unnecessary: Angular does that for you. All you need is

```
updateDashNotesMethod(notes: Notes) {
    let url = `http://bla:4000/api/path/path/`;
    return this._http
               .put(url, notes)
               .map(res => res.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. Worked great!